# Time based GAS trigger disabled for internal error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a trigger to launch a function in GAS every 15 minutes starting from a precise time (every day). So the trigger has to run the script at (for example) 10:02 and then every 15 minutes: 10:17, 10:32, 10:47, 11:02, etc.

So I've found a great source to run a script in a certain time (without using atHour and nearminute(0) because they have a confidential interval of +/- 15 minutes), here is the source (big up for the guy David Weiss): https://github.com/davidtheweiss/Apps-Script-Season-3-Script-Service/blob/master/Episode%201.1.gs

And there you can find the adapted code of the trigger for my purpouse:

```js
function copyPicked(){

// code of the function I want to run

}

////////////////// TRIGGER

function immutableTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('mutableTrigger')
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(15)
  .create();
}

function mutableTrigger() {
  const today = new Date();
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const month = today.getMonth();
  const day = today.getDate();
  const functionName = 'copyPicked';

  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => {
    trigger.getHandlerFunction() === functionName ? ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger) : 0;
  });

  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)
  .timeBased()
  .at(new Date(year, month, day, 10, 02))
  .create();
}
```

The problem is that when I run the functions mutableTrigger and immutableTrigger they run perfectly and smoothly but then a time trigger is created with the name of the function I want to run (copyPicked) with a precise time (10:02) and at 10:02 the function is automatically disabled for internal error! Why?

I found this could be a problem related to the runtime: V8 runtime has an issue with this type of time triggers -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612

So I tried to enable the old runtime: `DEPRECATED_ES5` as described in the above issue but  it gives me a generic error at this point of the code related to the trigger:

```
ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => {
```

I don't know this old runtime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it myself but I have no problem with running `copyPicked`.

Have you provided enough permission for `copyPicked`?

Arrow function (`trigger => {`) is not available in ES5

Comment: I've given the permission with my Google account to copyPicked when asked (because it has to open a file id in a shared drive), do you meant other permissions?
And what could I use instead of the arrow function to correct the code with ES5?
Thank you very much

Comment: @marcoversus I do not know the solution for your problem because I do not even face it. If you want to try with ES5, change `trigger => {` into `function(trigger) {`.

Comment: Now it's working! I simply changed the arrow function with function(trigger) as you said in the last comment and now everything works fine with ES5. Thank you very much, answer accepted